How to preserve user name, and possibly other part of credentials in Spring Security login form in SpringBoot context?
Spring web security allows redirecting back to the login form if authentication fails. Unfortunately, the user is presented with an empty log in form and is forced to re-type the name and other parts of the form. Is there a way to preserve/repopulate the user name after the authentication failure?

Then you need to save the form details in the local browser session storage and use it while the login form loading. But I think for this you need to write your custom html and css files.
